# pandas styling - how to hover already styled dataframe?

Tags: python, html, pandas

i want to be able to hover already styled pandas dataframe,  similarly as in the pandas example documentation (but there was no additional styling except of hovering).
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html (find keyword hover).
can you help? is it possible? to be honest, i'm not familiar with html/css.
below you can find my code, and how it looks now in a picture. 
I guess there something needs to be done with hierarchy?

[example_of_a_styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFDjJ.jpg)

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from IPython.display import HTML

cm1 = ListedColormap(sns.color_palette('YlOrRd'))

def hover(hover_color="#ffff99"):
    return dict(selector="tr:hover",
                props=[("background-color", "%s" % hover_color)])

styles = [hover(),
    dict(selector='th', 
         props=[('background-color', 'rgb(176, 206, 236)'),
                                      ('color', 'white')])]

pd.DataFrame({'first_col': [1,2,3],
              'second_col': [4,5,6]}).style.background_gradient(cmap=cm1, axis=None).set_table_styles(styles)
```